# In Selenium WebDriver, for loop is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've this page which asks for scores for 16 different rows, which are auto generated. I want to insert scores in each row. If I run below code just for 1 row (i.e. without for loop), it works fine. But when I run it for more than 1 row, it doesn't work at all.

In code, inside the for loop, first cssSelector is for a button. By clicking it will ask for scores for two tests, following with save button.

I've used variable i of for loop with first cssSelector for changing the row.

**Main code :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

/**
* @author KARAN
* MYRACECONTROL
*/
public class mrc {
/**
* @param args
* @throws InterruptedException 
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
int max = 100;
int min = 0;
int rndm = 0;
String rdm;
WebElement edit_button;

System.out.flush();

//Create firefoxDriver Object.
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\eclipse\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// LOGIN 
driver.get("http://ec2####-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/login");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("admin@admin.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/input")).sendKeys("admin");
edit_button = w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/button[1]")));
edit_button.click();

// JUDGEPANEL
// Navigate to judge panel
driver.navigate().to("http://ec2####-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/judgepanel");

// select event
Select drpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selector")));
drpdwn.selectByValue("70");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/button")).click();

// enter scores
for (int i=1; i<=16; i++) {
//edit_button = w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#entranceList > div:nth-child("+(i+1)+") > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)")));
//edit_button.click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#entranceList > div:nth-child("+(i+1)+") > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)")).click();
System.out.println("Button "+ (i+1) +" Pressed");
rndm = (int)(Math.random()*((max-min)+1));
System.out.println(rndm);
rdm = String.valueOf(rndm);
System.out.println(rdm);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modalSlideUp\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(rdm);
rndm = (int)(Math.random()*((max-min)+1));
System.out.println(rndm);
rdm = String.valueOf(rndm);
System.out.println(rdm);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modalSlideUp\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(rdm);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modalSlideUp\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/button")).click();
System.out.println("Save Button "+ (i+1) +" Pressed");
Thread.sleep(10);
}
}
}
```

**Error :**

```
1525848260543   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1525848260563   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4627
1525848261468   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\karan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.r5X2ICjOSWCR"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1525848268080   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50000
1525848268827   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
May 09, 2018 12:14:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #entranceList > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'KARAN-VAIO', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 61.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 6740, moz:profile: C:\Users\karan\AppData\Loca..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 843fa034-f2ad-40ea-a73c-b43a3f9cfebd
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#entranceList > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at mrc.main(mrc.java:71)
```

**Sample HTML Code :**

```
<!-- 1st ROW -->
<div ng-if="!isLocked &amp;&amp; !Userlock" class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entrance in entranceList">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ng-binding">
                Roma G
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--      run1 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 1 score" ng-model=entrance.run1> -->
                run1 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run1" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--     run2 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 2 score" ng-model=entrance.run2> -->
                run2 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run2" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--     <button class="button" ng-click=saveEntraceScore(entrance)> Save</button> -->
                <button id="disablerun" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditEntraceScore(entrance)"> Edit
                <!-- <div ng-if="isbattleTree === true" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </div> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd ROW -->
<div ng-if="!isLocked &amp;&amp; !Userlock" class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entrance in entranceList">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ng-binding">
                Jenna M
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--      run1 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 1 score" ng-model=entrance.run1> -->
                run1 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run1" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--     run2 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 2 score" ng-model=entrance.run2> -->
                run2 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run2" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <!--     <button class="button" ng-click=saveEntraceScore(entrance)> Save</button> -->
                <button id="disablerun" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditEntraceScore(entrance)"> Edit
                <!-- <div ng-if="isbattleTree === true" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </div> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And so on for other rows..

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: `#entranceList > div:nth-child(i+1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)` having this kind of locators is a really really bad idea.

Comment: @demouser123  Yes but nothing is unique, no meta-tags, no ids, not even xPaths. So I've to go with this. The reason is, because all the rows are auto-generated.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML or preferably a link to the page. Please fix the indent of your code. It's hard to read. Update the code with what you are currently using and update the (full) error message.

Comment: @JeffC Sorry brother,  but this is the fully intended code which I'm using right now. And error is full console output. I can't post HTML here or provide you link. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You posted in the comments in the answer below that you tried the updated code and had a new error message. Update the code in your question with whatever current code you are using and post the full error message. You can post HTML here and we're going to need it if you want us to help with this. There's no reason you can't post at least the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC I've updated my stuff as you asked. Pls look into it.

Comment: @JeffC Have you seen it yet? Pls give me some solution here, brother.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to click with the locators you have posted since we don't have all the relevant HTML. Which button are you trying to click first? The Edit button? Then you enter scores into Run 1 score `INPUT` and then Run 2 score `INPUT` and then click the Save button?

Comment: Yes That's the exact scenario here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of CSS selector
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div["+i+"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/button")).click();

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error you get is because your selector is invalid. Inside the selector you write (i+1) and expect that it is computed. However everything inside the "" is regarded a literal string, so nothing is done with your variable. You can fix this by string concatenation eg `"div:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")"` (As a condensed example). Or you can use String.format e.g. `String selector = String.format("div:nth-child(%d)", i+1);`

Comment: Ok I tried your suggestion. Now the error is updated with, 
`Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#entranceList > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1)}`

Comment: Well, than it seems you've moved on! It would be good to see the full stack trace and any relevant stuff. ( Is it still InvalidSelectorException or something else? ). You can just update the stuff you posted above.

Comment: Ah, so now you have got a completely different error. The idea of stack overflow is to have specific answers to specific questions. It is a good idea to mind this. Anyway, right now it says that your element can not be found. So this is a matter of getting the right css/xpath to the desired element. If the html is very difficult in this sense, in that there are no clear class names or id's, as a tester you may consider it your responsability to argue for better testable code. I personally consider that to be part of my job "providing insight in quality and risks to product and process" .

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, I'll keep that in mind. But the thing is, we don't have contact of our HTML developer anymore. So do you have any feasible solution of this?

Comment: I don't know what wou want to do. You can use developer tools from chrome (or other browsers) to help you find the correct css. Right click inspect and then select there and play around until you find a correct css that will give you a unique result.

Comment: Oh okay. I know that. Thanks anyway.